# back end remote-server/database for phonegap app

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

A database for a survey app,During the survey data is stored locally on the phone. after some surveys are done the users connects to the internet via WiFi or cellular  network and simply syncs the data to the cloud. Ultimately what i want to do is fetch this data for a travel guide application which includes GPS location mapped on a google map, name, address etc which i'm going to be building later on, so my question which cloud/remote server can use preferably free of charge.

Comment: Please give you post a better structure that would help a lot to make it more readable. Thanks.

Comment: ok, in short what what i'm asking is, backend DB for phonegap app which is not of course local  (E.g: sqlite,indexDB) but remote(cloud) DB. like for example google clouds sql server but its not free. i hope its much clear now

Comment: Just edit your question and not add infos here via comment. You can simply edit it via the Edit button. Also deliver code and an image if you can.